# What's the required torque for a flywheel?

Tags: dc-motor

What's the required calculate to estimate the required torque for a dc motor to spin up a 10 pound (4.53kg) flywheel with a 6 inch (152mm) diameter up to 10000 rpms?

Comment: It STILL depends how long you've got. Edit enough additional info into your other question and someone might be able to answer it.

Comment: If there is no friction, any torque will do if you are prepared to wait long enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for 30000+ rpm DC motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/530957/looking-for-30000-rpm-dc-motor)

Comment: Won't the "friction" resistance depend on the inertia of the flywheel?

Comment: No. It may depend on the *weight* of the flywheel though, except for non-contact bearings.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in addition to being unanswerably underspecified the question is one of applying physics to a topic of mechanical rather than electrical engineering.

Comment: similar question to `how much thrust is required to reach lightspeed for a 1000 ton spacecraft?`

Comment: No not at all similar. If you knew anything about general Relativity you would know that would require an infinite amount of energy.

Comment: Depends on the time and the moment of inertia of the flywheel. If the mass is concentrated at the rim (as it likely would be for a well-designed flywheel) then it will be more than (approaching double) if it was a simple disk.

Comment: @Aneikei "*Won't the "friction" resistance depend on the inertia of the flywheel?*" No. The friction torque depends on the mass of the fly wheelsitting on the bearings and the coefficient of friction, but not the inertia.  Friction for objects moving in a straight line along a surface depends on the mass, which also happens to be same as the inertia, but this isn't the case for spinning objects. The inertia of spinning objects depends on both the mass and distribution of that mass, whereas the friction on the bearings only continues to be dependent on the mass.

Comment: @Aneikei okay then, how much thrust is required to reach *half* lightspeed for a 1000 ton spacecraft?

Comment: It's not about thrust. It's about energy.

Answer (score 1):

The weight is irrelevant, but friction and balance are important. Assuming the motor can get the flywheel up to speed without burning out, even the smallest torque will be enough no matter how much it weighs - if you wait long enough.

However bearing friction and [windage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windage) will cause a continuous torque load that increases with speed. At 10,000 rpm the windage could be significant, and any imbalance will increase bearing loss as well as transferring energy to the motor mount. This is what will limit speed, because it increases current draw which drops more voltage inside the motor and reduces rpm.

Furthermore, in your [other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/530957/looking-for-30000-rpm-dc-motor) you say:-

> The motor(s) would be connected to a 29 mm diameter (3.58 inch
> circumference) **rubber wheel positioned and making contact** with a
> 16 inch circumference groove in the side of the flywheel."

So right there is an extra source of friction, bearing loss, and possible imbalance that will put your calculations out.

The easiest way to determine how much motor power you need will probably be to simply try it with a motor and see how much power it draws at different speeds compared to an unloaded motor.